# RPi.GPIO RuntimeError

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

So I am getting an error: `RuntimeError: Not running on a RPi!`
When the python script tries to setup a pin.

This script worked when I ran it from an SD card, but now I have an external SSD connected via a USB port, and the script doesn't work anymore.
I have been searching for an answer for quite a while, but haven't found anything on how to fix it.

The RaspberryPI 4 is using the SSD as a primary data storage.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(2, GPIO.OUT)
```

Comment: Please include your python script or relevant snippets of python script in the question.

Comment: @Natolio I have added a snippet of the script

Comment: What user is the script running as? Do they belong to the `gpio` group?

Comment: I am running the script as "ubuntu" (the default user), and yes this user is added to the group gpio

Comment: Can you check permissions on `/dev/memgpio` and verify that your user has read/write permissions on it? Take a look at this thread: https://github.com/gpiozero/gpiozero/issues/837

Comment: I don't have ```/dev/memgpio``` folder. I only have ```/dev/gpiochip0``` and  ```/dev/gpiochip1```

Comment: What are the ownership and permissions on `/dev/gpiochip0` and `/dev/gpiochip1`?

Comment: crwxrwxrwx 1 root root 254, 0 Jan 10 04:07 gpiochip0
crw-rwxrwx 1 root root 254, 1 Jan 10 04:07 gpiochip1

Comment: Perhaps it does not recognise a RPi4B, you need al least v0.7.0 of RPi.GPIO.

Comment: ```ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ gpio -v
gpio version: 2.50
Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Gordon Henderson
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type: gpio -warranty

Raspberry Pi Details:
  Type: Unknown17, Revision: 04, Memory: 0MB, Maker: Sony
  * Device tree is enabled.
  *--> Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.4
  * Root or sudo required for GPIO access.```

Comment: I have no idea wht you have given that. Do you have at least v0.7.0 of RPi.GPIO installed?

Comment: Yes I have the latest, v0.7.0, version of RPi.GPIO.